# How to reduce the image size inside an icon?

Tags: shortcode, images, icon

The below image is a shortcode and it has a separate image.
The white Gear in the image is a separate image in size of 32*32 and the blue is a background color for it. 
I just need   **to minimize the gear image to smaller.**
[image: dfs]
I need to set the icon like this: https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/set-blue-white-circular-buttons-mobile-phone-applications-web-collection-icons-use-42638187.jpg

Checkout the fifth image on the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest way to recude the image size will be to write some CSS.

Find the CSS class(es)/id(s) of that icon, and in your theme's style.css:

```
.icon-class{
    width:20px;
}
```

If the image doesn't go smaller, then you'll need to set it's `width` or `max-width` to `100%', and make it's`heightauto` whilst you're at it.

If the image is actually an icon, then write the CSS rule accordingly.

The side-effect of doing it with CSS maybe that the image may become 'blurry', especially if it's a `png`.

In this case, you'll probably want to replace the actual image with a naturally smaller one....

In this case, you'll have to put the image in your own theme's directory and copy all the shortcode's code into your theme (to avoid overriding if the third-party shortcode ever gets updated) and change the image's path to your own image.